# How to access this variable from my store / state in my vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have setup my routes.js file to import my state from my store.  This is working as when I `console.log(state)` it outputs my store to console successfully:

[image]

I then define my route as below:

**routes.js**

```js
   
import { state } from './store/store';
// import { mapState, mapGetters } from "vuex";

console.log(state)

const routes = [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  name: 'dashboard',
  component: Dashboard,
},
{
  path: '/project/:id',
  name: 'project',
  component: Project,
  props: true,
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
  },

  children: [
        {
          path: 'module/:module',
          name: 'module',
          component: Tasks,
          props: true,

          children: [
                  {
                    path: 'task/:url',
                    name: 'task',
                    component:  () => import(`./components/ProductServiceAnalysis/${$state.taskURL}.vue`),
                    props: true,
```

I am getting the error:
`app.js:59653 [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: ReferenceError: state is not defined` in relation to the second last line where I try to access the state.taskURL variable.

Why is this erroring?  And how can I access my taskURL variable in my store from my Router?

If I am approaching this incorrectly then please offer suggestions.

**This is my store.js:**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex);
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://buildmybusiness.test/api'

Vue.config.devtools = true;

export const state = {
 token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
 requiredTask: 'This is my current task',
 currentModule: '1',
 currentModuleName: 'Product & Service Analysis',
 currentTask: '1',
 modules:[],
 tasks:[],
 taskName:[],
 actions:[],
 userId: localStorage.getItem('loggedin_user') || null,
 userName: localStorage.getItem('loggedin_username') || null,
 projects:[],
 currentProjectId: '',
 currentProjectName: '',
 taskURL: 'define-product-service'
}

export const store = new Vuex.Store({

 state,

 mutations: {
  SET_MODULES: (state, payload) => {
   state.modules = payload;
  },

  SET_TASKS: (state, tasks) => {
   state.tasks = tasks;
  },

  SET_MODULE_TITLE: (state, moduleTitle) => {
   state.currentModuleName = moduleTitle
  },

  SET_ACTIONS: (state, payload) => {
   state.actions = payload;
  },

  RETRIEVE_TOKEN: (state, token) => {
   state.token = token;
  },
  DESTROY_TOKEN: (state) => {
   state.token = null;
  },
  SET_USERID: (state, userid) => {
   state.userId = userid;
  },
  DESTROY_USERID: (state) => {
   state.userId = null;
  },


  SET_USERNAME: (state, username) => {
   state.userName = username;
  },
  DESTROY_USERNAME: (state) => {
   state.userName = '';
  },


  SET_PROJECTS: (state, projects) => {
   state.projects = projects;
  },
  DESTROY_PROJECTS: (state) => {
   state.projects = [];
  },


  SET_PROJECT_ID: (state, projectId) => {
   state.currentProjectId = projectId;
  },
  SET_PROJECT_NAME: (state, projectName) => {
   state.currentProjectName = projectName;
  },


  SET_ACTION_URL: (state, taskURL) => {
   state.taskURL = taskURL;
  },

 },

 getters: {

  loggedIn(state){
   return state.token !== null;
  },

  SelectedTaskURL(state) {
   return state.taskURL;
  }
 },

 actions: {

  setActionsURL(context, taskURL){

   context.commit("SET_ACTION_URL", taskURL);

  },

  setProject(context, projectDetails){

   const projectId = projectDetails.projectId;
   const projectName = projectDetails.projectName;

   context.commit("SET_PROJECT_ID", projectId);
    context.commit("SET_PROJECT_NAME", projectName);

  },

  fetchProjects(context) {

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token;
    return axios.get('/project').then(response => {

      const projectNames = response.data.map(project => project);
      context.commit("SET_PROJECTS", projectNames);

    });
  },

  getUserDetails(context) {

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token;
    return axios.get('/user').then(response => {


     const userid = response.data.id
      localStorage.setItem('loggedin_user', userid)
      context.commit("SET_USERID", userid);

     const username = response.data.name
      localStorage.setItem('loggedin_username', username)
      context.commit("SET_USERNAME", username);
     });
  },

  register(context, data) {
   return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post('/register', {
     name: data.name,
     email: data.email,
     password: data.password,
    })
    .then(response => {

     resolve(response)

    })
    .catch(error => {

     reject(error);
    })
   })
  },

  destroyToken(context){
   axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token

   if (context.getters.loggedIn){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
     axios.post('/logout')
     .then(response => {

      localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
      context.commit("DESTROY_TOKEN")
      context.commit("DESTROY_USERID")
      context.commit("DESTROY_USERNAME")
      context.commit("DESTROY_PROJECTS")
      resolve(response)

     })
     .catch(error => {
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
      context.commit("DESTROY_TOKEN")
      context.commit("DESTROY_USERID")
      context.commit("DESTROY_USERNAME")
      context.commit("DESTROY_PROJECTS")
      reject(error);
     })
    })

   }
  },

   loadModules(context) {

     axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token
       return axios.get('/modules').then(response => {

           context.commit("SET_MODULES", response.data);
           });
   },

   getTasks(context, moduleDetails){


    var moduleTitle = moduleDetails.moduleName;
    var moduleTitle = (moduleTitle === undefined) ? moduleTitle = 'Product & Service Analysis' : moduleTitle;
    //console.log(moduleTitle);

    var moduleId = moduleDetails.moduleId;
    var moduleId = (moduleId === undefined) ? moduleId = 1 : moduleId;

     return axios.get(`project/${context.state.currentProjectId}/module/${moduleId}`)
      .then(response => {
       context.commit("SET_TASKS", response.data);

       context.commit("SET_MODULE_TITLE", moduleTitle);
      });
   },

   loadTasks(context, tasks){

   },

   loadActions(context){


   },

   retrieveToken(context, credentials){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
     axios.post('/login', {
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
     })
     .then(response => {
      const token = response.data.access_token

      localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
      context.commit("RETRIEVE_TOKEN", token)
      resolve(response)

     })
     .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      reject(error);
     })
    })
   },
 }

});
```

my **app.js**

```js
// main.js

require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
import routes from './routes';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { store } from './store/store';
import Vuex from 'vuex'


Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(Vuex);

const router = new VueRouter({
  
  store,
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!store.getters.loggedIn) {
      next({
        name: 'login',
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
      next({
        name: 'dashboard',
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})

new Vue({
    store: store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```

**If reference to @shazyriver:**

I have done as you suggested.  I have put a `console.log(`./components/ProductServiceAnalysis/${state.taskURL}.vue`);` before `const routes = [ ...` which correctly accesses the taskURL property and prints it to console.  However, it still fails with a 'state undefined' when it tries to access the same property from within the route itself - even though it works when accessed outside the `const routes = [`:

[image]

See console log for detail

Comment: Do you get this error already at build time?

Comment: Try `${state.taskURL}.vue` ?

Comment: You should not be able to "import" state like you did. This is most likely the initial state. You would need the mapper that you commented out to access Vuex state. Additionally, why would you need to access Vuex state in your router definition?

Comment: 1) I don't get the error at build time.  Just when i perform an action that tries to access that component.

2) ${state.taskURL}.vue gives the same error.

3) I need to access the state because taskURL stores the slug that is used to access a particular component - I'm using dynamic imports to do this

Comment: @RDowns are `:url` route param and `taskURL` have the same value?

Comment: @RDowns please check my edit. This should do it.

Comment: @MaxSinev yes they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your configuration and all your imports are correct.

It's very interesting issue...I have researched it and can conclude that there is a kind of bug in transpilation process of webpack+babel. Let me explain:

If you check your bundle you can see that there is strange untranspiled `concat` expression in your dynamic `import`  line, something like this: `("./".concat(state.taskURL,".vue"))` - but `state` should be wrapped with webpack helpers but it wasn't...Looks like module resolving was skipped for `import` statement string interpolation.

The simplest solution is just assign imported module to some variable and use that variable in the `import` statement(*I recommend to use fully configured store instead of state*):

```
import { store } from './store/store';
let storeVar = store;
//...
//...below
    component:  () => import(`./components/ProductServiceAnalysis/${storeVar.state.taskURL}.vue`),
```

In this case module will be processed correctly by webpack.

P.S. I had created clean project with just webpack and tried to play with dynamic imports and they was resolved successfully...So I suppose that issue in another transpilation layer, maybe babel.

P.P.S. If my explanation is not enough clear please feel free to ask in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import it like:

```
import store from './store/store.js'
```

Then you can use it like:

```
store.commit('increaseCounter')
```